# Converting File Number to Date--Python/matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm currently working with files of data that are chronologically sorted by number, starting with 0000000120 and moving upwards in increments of 120 (so the next is 0000000240, etc). Each file moves forward 5 days, so if 0000000120 is 1/1/02, then 0000000240 would be 1/5/02 and so on. I'm trying to convert these numbers to dates to display on my figures made with the data, so that I can more easily see seasonal progression. I've been messing around with datetime and such, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to go from file number to python-friendly date. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Maybe post some of what you've tried.  Generally speaking, you can get file names from a location in Python using `os.listdir(path)`

Answer (score 0):

```
date_1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, "%m/%d/%y")

for i, num in enumerate(filenums):
    num /= 120
    endDates+=[date_1 + datetime.timedelta(days=i*5)]
```